# How should I parse Infinity with Double?

Tags: c#, parsing, double, infinity

If I try

```
Double.Parse("Infinity")
```

I get

```
Double.Parse("Infinity") threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException'
```

Why? And what should I do if I want to parse it anyway and get a Double with the value Infinity?

Comment: Good question taking into account other languages as well. "-unendlich" or "-Infinity"..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just found this out:

```
Decimal.Parse("Infinity", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

will work and return a double with the value +Infinity.

The reason it did not work is that I am not, I think, automatically in the InvariantCulture but perhaps in the de-DE culture which does not handle the exact string "Infinity". (Perhaps it would handle some other string.)

Comment: How come this is marked as Accepted answer. This code simply does not work! "Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 8):

All the below parsing are valid, since your ***system settings are different is causing the issue***. As [dontomaso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246622/dontomaso) had answered above just need to add the Invariant Culture.

```
Double.Parse("NaN", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Double.Parse("-Infinity", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Double.Parse("Infinity", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try this:

```
if(yourstring.ToLower() == "infinity")
{
   yourdouble = double.PositiveInfinity;
}
```

Comment: I'd make it `if (yourstring.ToUpper() == "INFINITY")` just in case ;)

Comment: What about the regional settings and different languages?

Comment: For this to always work, you should use `yourstring.ToLowerInvariant()`. If you don't use invariant, it may fail to match due to the famous [Turkish Lowercase i](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/) problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [double.PositiveInfinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.positiveinfinity.aspx) .The value of this constant is the result of dividing a positive number by zero.

```
double infinity = double.PositiveInfinity;
```

Answer (score 2):

.NET has inconsistent behavior for parsing infinity and negative infinity depending on culture.

If you are using the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, the strings to use are `"Infinity"` and `"-Infinity"`.

```
var infinity = double.Parse("Infinity", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var negativeInfinity = double.Parse("-Infinity", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

However, if you are in a specific culture, the strings to use are `"∞"` and `"-∞"`.

```
var infinity = double.Parse("∞", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
var negativeInfinity = double.Parse("-∞", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem that there are strings that will parse to infinity and negative infinity that work in every culture by default, including `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. If you try to parse `"∞"` or `"-∞"` using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, it will throw a `FormatException`.

### Workaround

If you don't mind adding an additional helper method, you could make this work in any culture by changing the `NumberFormatInfo.PostiveInfinitySymbol` and `NumberFormatInfo.NegativeInfinitySymbol` to make every culture parse the strings you want.

```
public static IFormatProvider NormalizeInfinity(
    string positiveInfinitySymbol = "Infinity",
    string negativeInfinitySymbol = "-Infinity")
{
    return NormalizeInfinity(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, positiveInfinitySymbol, negativeInfinitySymbol);
}

public static IFormatProvider NormalizeInfinity(
    IFormatProvider provider,
    string positiveInfinitySymbol = "Infinity",
    string negativeInfinitySymbol = "-Infinity")
{
    NumberFormatInfo numberFormat;
    if (provider is null)
    {
        numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
    }
    else
    {
        numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)((NumberFormatInfo)provider.GetFormat(typeof(NumberFormatInfo))).Clone();
    }
    numberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol = positiveInfinitySymbol;
    numberFormat.NegativeInfinitySymbol = negativeInfinitySymbol;
    return numberFormat;
}
```

Usage

```
double infinity = double.Parse("Infinity", NormalizeInfinity());
double negativeInfinity = double.Parse("-Infinity", NormalizeInfinity());

double aDouble = double.Parse("1.23456", NormalizeInfinity());

double notANumber = double.Parse("NaN", NormalizeInfinity());
```

Note the above will work with the same symbols for infinity and negative infinity regardless if you set the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or not.

You can also pass through any culture and it will change the infinity and negative infinity settings, but leave all of the others intact.

```
double infinity = double.Parse("Infinity", NormalizeInfinity(new CultureInfo("de")));
```